# Deterministic classification in R using regular expressions?

Tags: r, loops, classification, text-classification

I have of list of regular expressions:

```
regex_list <- list("First Name" = "^[A-Za-z]+$",
                   "Postal Code" = "^[0-9]{5}$",
                   "Email" = "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}")
```

And then I have a list of strings to be classified:

```
strings <- c(
  "John", "12345", "john.doe@email.com", "InvalidString", 
  "Alice", "54321", "example.com", "Bob", "67890", "contact@example.org",
  "Charlie", "98765", "test.email@test.co.uk", "David", "13579", "invalid.email",
  "Eva", "24680", "eva.smith@example.com", "Frank", "11111", "frank@email"
)
```

Now, I would like to classify each and every string according to the regex_list. While this can be achieved using two nested loops:

```
# Initialize an empty vector for categories
categories <- character(length(strings))

# Categorize the strings based on the regular expressions
for (i in 1:length(strings)) {
  for (j in 1:length(regex_list)) {
    if (grepl(regex_list[[j]], strings[i])) {
      categories[i] <- names(regex_list)[j]
      break
    }
  }
  # If it doesn't fit into any category, set it to "No Category"
  if (is.na(categories[i])) {
    categories[i] <- "No Category"
  }
}
```

...I was thinking a more elegant way of achieving this. What it could be? :)

Comment: If, for some reason, you want to continue with a for-loop, you better do `categories <- rep(x = "No Category", times = length(strings))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple approach:

```r
found <- apply(sapply(regex_list, grepl, x = strings), 1, function(z) which(z)[1])
replace(names(regex_list)[found], is.na(found), "No Category")
#  [1] "First Name"  "Postal Code" "Email"       "First Name"  "First Name"  "Postal Code" "No Category" "First Name"  "Postal Code" "Email"       "First Name"  "Postal Code" "Email"       "First Name" 
# [15] "Postal Code" "No Category" "First Name"  "Postal Code" "Email"       "First Name"  "Postal Code" "No Category"
```

This works by first creating a `matrix` of "found" or not:

```r
sapply(regex_list, grepl, x = strings)
#       First Name Postal Code Email
#  [1,]       TRUE       FALSE FALSE
#  [2,]      FALSE        TRUE FALSE
#  [3,]      FALSE       FALSE  TRUE
#  [4,]       TRUE       FALSE FALSE
#  [5,]       TRUE       FALSE FALSE
#  [6,]      FALSE        TRUE FALSE
#  [7,]      FALSE       FALSE FALSE
#  [8,]       TRUE       FALSE FALSE
#  [9,]      FALSE        TRUE FALSE
# [10,]      FALSE       FALSE  TRUE
# [11,]       TRUE       FALSE FALSE
# [12,]      FALSE        TRUE FALSE
# [13,]      FALSE       FALSE  TRUE
# [14,]       TRUE       FALSE FALSE
# [15,]      FALSE        TRUE FALSE
# [16,]      FALSE       FALSE FALSE
# [17,]       TRUE       FALSE FALSE
# [18,]      FALSE        TRUE FALSE
# [19,]      FALSE       FALSE  TRUE
# [20,]       TRUE       FALSE FALSE
# [21,]      FALSE        TRUE FALSE
# [22,]      FALSE       FALSE FALSE
```

Most of these have one `TRUE` per row, but some have nothing, so we need to be a little careful here. I'll use `apply` to operate row-wise (the `MARGIN=1` means to operate on each row):

```r
sapply(regex_list, grepl, x = strings) |>
  apply(MARGIN = 1, function(z) which(z)[1])
#  [1]  1  2  3  1  1  2 NA  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2 NA  1  2  3  1  2 NA
```

The `which(z)` gives us which within each row, but when nothing is found it will return an empty vector; the `[1]` however forces it to return `NA` in this case (and returns the first match when there is a true).

Those numbers are indices on `regex_list`, so we can next index the names on them, replacing the `NA` with the no-category label.

Answer (score 2):

`grepl()` is vectorized over `x` so you only need one `for` loop:

```r
categories <- rep('No Category', length(strings))
matched <- rep(F, length(strings))

for (i in seq_along(regex_list)) {
  match.i <- grepl(regex_list[[i]], strings[!matched])
  categories[!matched][match.i] <- names(regex_list)[i]
  matched[!matched][match.i] <- T
}
```

In every loop run only the strings which haven't been classified yet are matched.

```r
cbind(strings, categories)
#       strings                 categories   
#  [1,] "John"                  "First Name" 
#  [2,] "12345"                 "Postal Code"
#  [3,] "john.doe@email.com"    "Email"      
#  [4,] "InvalidString"         "First Name" 
#  [5,] "Alice"                 "First Name" 
#  [6,] "54321"                 "Postal Code"
#  [7,] "example.com"           "No Category"
#  [8,] "Bob"                   "First Name" 
#  [9,] "67890"                 "Postal Code"
# [10,] "contact@example.org"   "Email"      
# [11,] "Charlie"               "First Name" 
# [12,] "98765"                 "Postal Code"
# [13,] "test.email@test.co.uk" "Email"      
# [14,] "David"                 "First Name" 
# [15,] "13579"                 "Postal Code"
# [16,] "invalid.email"         "No Category"
# [17,] "Eva"                   "First Name" 
# [18,] "24680"                 "Postal Code"
# [19,] "eva.smith@example.com" "Email"      
# [20,] "Frank"                 "First Name" 
# [21,] "11111"                 "Postal Code"
# [22,] "frank@email"           "No Category"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following using some matrix algebra. N.B.! This solution works iff the categories are mutually exclusive! (At least implicitly that was the case in my example.)

```
#The first line creates a length(strings) times length(regex_list) matrix
sapply(regex_list, FUN = grepl, x = strings, perl = TRUE) %>%

#The second line is a matrix product involving the matrix and a vector of consecutive integers ranging from zero to length(regex_list) 
  {c(. %*% seq(regex_list))} %>%

#Now, we have a vector of integers, each integer representing a category i.e. the index of an element in the names(regex_list) vector. Additionally, we might have zeroes representing no category elements.
#At this point we can use ifelse (which is vectorized), and pass it the vector, and defining zero as "no category", while matching all other integers with the corresponding regex_list names.
  {ifelse(.==0,"No Category",names(regex_list)[.])}
```